# why is unicode value different for symbol '' in nodejs and python?

Tags: python, node.js, unicode

Why is unicode value of symbol '' is different in nodejs and python.

nodejs (version 8.11) gives "".charCodeAt(0) output as 55357

where as python (version 2.7 or 3.6) ord(''[0]) output as 128515

as per https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f603/index.htm 128515 is correct. 
so why is nodejs giving different number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because JavaScript does not implement proper Unicode encoding (that addresses 1114112 code points), but UCS-2 (which only addresses 65536). The so-called astral characters are encoded in JavaScript as two UCS-2 characters; your `charCodeAt(0)` only shows you the first of them.

There is a new function in JavaScript that fixes this:

```js
console.log("".codePointAt(0))
```

MDN has a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt#Polyfill) where you can learn the maths behind the translation.

Comment: Technically that's not UCS-2 anymore but rather UTF-16, since it includes surrogate characters.

Comment: @DanielPryden: It's a matter of perspective. The underlying data is encoded as if it was UTF-16; but JavaScript treats it as if it is UCS-2 (ignoring the semantics of the surrogate characters), except at display-time, and in `codePointAt`. The difference is the same as ASCII-8bit vs UTF-8: `"\xF0\x9F\x98\x83"` is technically the same as `""` (UTF-8-encoded), but all I see is four bytes when it's presented like this.

Comment: I guess? The point is, emoji and other characters outside the BMP *cannot* be represented in UCS-2. UCS-2 as an encoding format predates their existence, and could not be retrofitted to include them. UTF-16 was created to replace UCS-2; UTF-16 can contain characters from other planes by using surrogates. If you have a string containing surrogate characters, I would call that UTF-16 and not UCS-2. JavaScript's problem is that many API functions (including `codePointAt`, unfortunately) haven't been upgraded to understand UTF-16, and can't be without changing how characters are indexed.

Comment: @DanielPryden: You misunderstand what I'm saying. `""` is undoubtedly encoded as UTF-16. But JavaScript _treats it_ as if it was UCS-2, because it never understood UTF-16 properly (till recently, with `codePointAt`). The surrogate characters are there, but JavaScript doesn't understand them. If it did, `""[0] == ""`; but while that's `true` in Ruby, it is `false` in JavaScript. If JavaScript worked with UTF-16, `"".length` would be 1, like in Ruby, not 2. It is 2 because for JavaScript, `""` is two unrelated UCS-2 characters, that are hacked into a UTF-16 character at display time.